# Adding a folder name to any end of the path

Tags: powershell

I am beginner for Powershell and have to needed little script. Actually I completed some part of my script by investigation in here with some question that are questioned before.

**folderaddress : C:\Users\Test\A\B**

There is 3 subfolder M1, M2, M3 in B folder means that under the "C:\Users\Test\A\B" path.
Firstly I brought all folders in this path with **Get-ChildItem**.

After this I will use inside  folders of M1 or M2 or M3 folders. For example I will bring subfolder of M1 folder firstly.  Then I will use for M2 folder and go on. These folders M1, M2, M3 dynamically will change so path of the these folders will change.

I want to add folder address path to name of the M1 forlder. End of the process the path should be:

**folderaddress : C:\Users\Test\A\M1 or C:\Users\Test\A\B\M2**

```
$names = Get-Childitem -Path C:\Users\Test\A -Directory -Name
$testadres  = "C:\Users\Test\A"
```

Actually I am trying to add to the end of the path subfolder name in script as a dynamically. End of the process new path shold be below:

`$newaddress = "C:\Users\Test\A\M1"` or `$newaddress = "C:\Users\Test\A\M2"`.

Comment: You can try `Get-Childitem -Path C:\Users\Test\A -Directory | Select -Expand FullName` to get the full paths of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list first level subdirectory paths, you can do the following:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\Users\Test\A -Directory | Select -Expand FullName
```

If you want to join a subdirectory name from one path (`$sourceDir`) to the end of another path (`$targetDir`), you can do the following:

```
$sourceDir = 'C:\Users\Test\A\B'
$targetDir = 'C:\Users\Test\A'
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Directory -Name | Foreach-Object {
    Join-Path -Path $targetDir -ChildPath $_
}
```

If at any point you want to query deeper than one level, you can add the `-Recurse` switch to [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Great Thanks!. Espically `Get-Childitem -Path C:\Users\Test\A -Directory | Select -Expand FullName ` commang really works in my code. Also it helps to me understand the some steps

Comment: @PALES, if this answer solves your issue, please consider marking the green check mark to make this an answer. It helps our future readers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this subject. I am new in here .